# Calculating average distance of the dart from a bullseye, with two different Gaussian random variables.

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Im a master student and this course is about probability and random processes. I had troubles with some of the material and therefore I started reading from the start again. The exercise im stuck with right now is:

> A large circular dartboard is set up with a "bullseye" at the center
>   of the circle, which is at the coordinate (0,0). A dart is thrown at
>   the center but lands at (X,Y), where X and Y are two different
>   Gaussian random variables. What is the average distance of the dart
>   from the bullseye?

By average distance I assume when you cast about 1000 times. I know a gaussian random variable can have values from the standard normal distribution. But how do I calculate the average distance?

I'm using matlab to solve it.

When its a bullseye I assume its a circle 
$$ 
r = \sqrt(x2 + y2)
$$

But im not sure if I have to use that equation?

I think I have to use the function randn in matlab. Since that's for the Gaussian Distribution.

I know that the answer is about 1,2381 (N = 1000).

I have struggled with this questions for some time and I have no idea how to start it. Can you guys give me a tips?

Comment: Are $X$ and  $Y$ independent? Are their means, variances known? I assume that kind of information was provided.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Nothing more was provided. But I know that the realization of a Gaussian random variable is obtained by using randn(1,1). But I cant figure out how to solve it.

Comment: Generate $X_i\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y_i\sim N(0,1)$. Compute $R_i=\sqrt{X_i^2+Y_i^2}$. Estimate $\bar r=\frac 1 N \sum_{i=1}^N R_i$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I translated your problem to python code. 
I assume whatever program you're using has similar functions.

I did use real random numbers though, not Gaussian randoms.

Code below for a circle with radius 1

x and y being the coordinates from -1 to 1 since r = 1

r the distance to bullseye by Pythagoras 
$\sqrt(x^2 + y^2)$

```
import random
i = 0
r_list = []
while i < 10**6:
    i += 1
    x = random.uniform(-1,1)
    y = random.uniform(-1,1)
    r = float(x**2 + y**2)**0.5
    r_list.append(r)
avg_r = float(sum(r_list)/i)     
print ("Complete after {0} iterations".format(i))
print ("Average dist to bullseye according to r list : {0}".format(avg_r))
```

which yields

```
Complete after 1000000 iterations
Average dist to bullseye according to r list : 0.764763180314
```

heres the code for Guassian random numbers

I had to use coordinates between 0 and 1 to get the result you wanted

aka darts would only be hitting the 1st quarter of the dartboard

```
import random
i = 0
r_list = []
while i < 10**6:
    i += 1
    x = random.gauss(0,1)
    y = random.gauss(0,1)
    r = float(x**2 + y**2)**0.5
    r_list.append(r)
avg_r = float(sum(r_list)/i)
print ("Complete after {0} iterations".format(i))
print ("Average dist to bullseye according to r list : {0}".format(avg_r))
```

yields:

```
Complete after 1000000 iterations
Average dist to bullseye according to r list : 1.25375619515
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It helped alot.